Getting {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"invalid_grant: invalid authorization code"} in Salesforce?
I am trying to get the Session ID for my salesforce using js force npm
const oauth2 = new jsforce.OAuth2({
    loginUrl : 'https://dev.my.salesforce.com',
    clientId : 'xxxx.uQ_XL3FVO9uyCxqCo',
    clientSecret : 'xxxx3ddd',
    redirectUri : 'http://localhost:3030/token'
});

What else I did:

Grant full access in my connected app settings
"All users can authorize themselfes"
Double checked client id, client secret


Check the exact authorization code that is generated. Sometimes the authorization code will be generated along with null or escape characters which needs to be replaced. E.g. Replace "%3D%3D" with "==".
This post may help:
https://socialscheduler.co/fix-invalid-grant-authorization-salesforce-error/
